# Using Scrapy, how do I send a POST request to web form (Without Login) and retrieve results?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to send a POST request to this form using Scrapy (http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx). Am i sending my payload (formdata) correctly?

1. I want to fill and submit my payload to the form fields [Form Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMB0O.png)
2. Retrieve the results from the resulting [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuM2m.png) using my parse_after_search function

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'greatriver'
    login_url = 'http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx'
    start_urls = [login_url]


    def parse(self, response):
        login_url = 'http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx'
        return FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                url=login_url,
                clickdata={'name': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch'},
                formdata = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlState': 'AK'},
                callback = self.parse_after_search,
        )

    def parse_after_search (self, response):
        print (response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvResults"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a'))
```

The Results when i run this script:

```
2023-04-20 20:00:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-04-20 20:00:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-04-20 20:00:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2023-04-20 20:00:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx> (referer: None)
2023-04-20 20:00:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx> (referer: http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx)
[]
2023-04-20 20:00:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-04-20 20:00:06 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Im expecting my response.xpath to return a string

Comment: What do you get in the response? If you are getting data back (that you expect) in the response then you're probably sending the form correctly and can rule that out. If there is a response I would try isolating the response and running tests on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is fine, you're getting an empty list because the selector is wrong (sometimes when using scrapy there's no `tbody`).

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'greatriver'
    login_url = 'http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx'
    start_urls = [login_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        login_url = 'http://www.umdata.org/SearchChurches.aspx'
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            url=login_url,
            clickdata={'name': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch'},
            formdata={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlState': 'AK'},
            callback=self.parse_after_search,
        )

    def parse_after_search (self, response):
        for line in response.xpath('//table[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvResults"]//tr[not(@style)]'):
            yield {
                'Church Name': line.xpath('./td[1]//text()').get(),
                'Conference': line.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get(),
                'District': line.xpath('./td[3]/text()').get(),
                'Location': line.xpath('./td[4]/text()').get(),
            }
```

Output:

```py
...
...
{'Church Name': 'FIRST UNITED METHODIST CHURCH OF ANCHORAGE', 'Conference': 'ALASKA', 'District': 'ALASKA', 'Location': 'ANCHORAGE, AK'}

{'Church Name': 'FIRST UNITED METHODIST CHURCH OF FAIRBANKS', 'Conference': 'ALASKA', 'District': 'ALASKA', 'Location': 'FAIRBANKS, AK'}
...
...
```